# Why does the Python runtime handle warnings this way?

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, deprecation-warning

Here's a traceback from a project I'm working on:

```
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py:13: PendingDeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
  import fnmatch, glob, traceback, errno, sys, atexit, locale, imp
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "./mouse16.py", line 1050, in _lit_string
    rangeof = range(self.idx.v, self.idx.v + result.span()[1])
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'span'
```

Now, there's a since-fixed bug in my code that caused the traceback itself; whatever.

I'm interested in the first line: the `PendingDeprecationWarning` for not-my-code. I use Ubuntu (as one can tell from `apport`'s existence in the path), which is well-known for packaging and relying on Python for many things, notably things like package management and bug reporting (`apport` / `ubuntu-bug`).

[`imp` is indeed deprecated: *"Deprecated since version 3.4: The imp package is pending deprecation in favor of importlib."*](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/imp.html#module-imp). My machine runs at least Python 3.4.3+ or better and it takes time and a lot of work to modernise and update software completely, so this warning is understandable.

But [my program](https://github.com/catb0t/mouse16) doesn't go anywhere *near* `imp`, `importlib` or `apport`, so my question is, why isn't a warning deriving from `apport`'s source written to `apport`'s logs or certainly collected by `stderr` on `apport`'s parent process?

If I had to take a guess at this, it's because the devs decided to buffer -- but never flush nor write -- `apport`'s `stderr`, and so the next time a `python` child process on the system opens `stderr` for writing (as an error in my program did), apport's buffered `stderr` is written too.

This isn't supported by what I (think I) know about Unix -- why would two separate Python instances interact in this way?

---

Upon request, here's the best I can do for an MCVE: a list of module-level imports.

```
import readline
import os
import sys
import warnings
import types
import typing
```

Is it because I import `warnings`? But... I still don't touch `apport`.

---

<sup>I think this question is more on-topic and will get better answers here on SO than [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com) or [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com); flag it for migration if you feel strongly otherwise but I think the mods will agree with me.</sup>

Comment: Could you clarify what you're actually asking?

Comment: The warning happens in the `apport` client library, which the Python process imports, not in the server process.

Comment: How is it unclear what I'm asking? I want to know why the warning shows up in a traceback for my code, and I posed that question in two different but similar ways exactly twice -- an answer can choose either or both or none.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo why does Python's runner need to import apport at runtime, then? That confuses me more.

Comment: I think the question made more sense when it was clearer the rest of the traceback was unrelated, but whatever ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Please include a [mcve] in the question itself, not as a link to a github repo. Your real question is that the python apport library is throwing a warning without you importing it.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo It's very hard to give an MCVE when I don't remotely understand what causes the warning -- surely, 1100 lines is not `minimal`. I thought it would be enough to say "I know for a fact I don't interface `apport`" and ask the question from there.

Comment: @cat Does an empty program cause the warning? Then it's likely a problem with Ubuntu's Python package. Is it the imports that cause the warning? Remove the rest of your code and see. Go through and see where the warning comes from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Apport docs](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Apport) state:

> If ... e. g. a packaged Python application raises an uncaught exception, the apport backend is automatically invoked

The copy of Python distributed by Ubuntu has been specifically modified to do this. The exception-handling has been modified/hooked, and the code that gets called when you cause an exception is triggering this warning.

Comment: ...my code isn't `packaged` in any real way, but this makes more sense.

Comment: Looking at the [source](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~apport-hackers/apport/trunk/view/head:/apport_python_hook.py), it appears that the Apport exception handler gets invoked for every exception and *then* if it determines it's running in a Ubuntu packaged program it logs/reports the crash.

Answer (score 2):

> so my question is, why isn't a warning deriving from apport's source written to apport's logs or certainly collected by stderr on apport's parent process?

The apport python library isn't running in a separate process here. Sure the actual apport process is separate, but you are interacting/binding to it with library that is local to your code/process.

Since this Python library is using a deprecated module, that is running inside of your process, Python is correctly warning you.

As per Andrew's answer, the apport library is automatically invoked with an uncaught exception.

Comment: What? Where does my code interact with `apport` or anything outside of its own runtime?